# Displaying Craft User Profile based on First and Last Name

Tags: user-profile

I don't want to ustilise the username or the ID of a user to get their profile info so I am using their first and last name. So far I can fetch the user based on first name:

```
{% set slug = 'first-last' %}
{% set firstNameSlug = slug|split('-')[0] %}
{% set lastNameSlug = slug|split('-')[1] %}

{% set user = craft.users.firstName(slug).first %}
```

How do I build on this code to fetch using the first name AND last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/user-queries.html#lastname

```
{% set slug = 'first-last'|split('-') %}
{% set firstNameSlug = slug[0] %}
{% set lastNameSlug = slug[1] %}

{% set user = craft.users.firstName(firstNameSlug).lastName(lastNameSlug).first %}
```

We only need to split once, so I spit the slug variable instead.

You were passing `slug` to the first name method, but you would want to pass `firstNameSlug`.

Alternately this can be written like this if you know the slug is correct:

```
{% set slug = 'first-last' %}
{% set user = craft.users.slug(slug).first %}
```

But you said you don't want to do that so I'll assume you know what you are doing.